# Computation expressions vs applicative functors and what not

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression, fsharpx

Not entirely sure the title describes it ok, but I do have about the following code:

paket.dependencies:

```
source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
nuget fsharpx.extras
nuget mongodb.driver
```

some.fsx:

```
#r @".\packages\MongoDB.Bson\lib\net45\MongoDB.Bson.dll"
#r @".\packages\MongoDB.Driver\lib\net45\MongoDB.Driver.dll"
#r @".\packages\MongoDB.Driver.Core\lib\net45\MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll"

#r @".\packages\FSharpX.Extras\lib\net45\FSharpX.Extras.dll"


open MongoDB
open MongoDB.Driver
open MongoDB.Bson 
open MongoDB.Bson.Serialization

open FSharpx.Choice

let private createClient (connectString:string) = MongoClient(connectString)
let CreateClient = protect createClient

let private getDb name (client:IMongoClient) = client.GetDatabase(name)
let GetDB1 name client =
    choose {
        let! c = client
        return! (protect (getDb name) c)
    }

let GetDB2 name (client:Choice<IMongoClient, exn>) =
    protect (getDb name)
    <!> client
```

The point for this "excersise" was to write GetDB2 so that it does the same as GetDB1 but use operators (applicatives?), but I am at the moment not able to turn my head to manage this.

The above code compiles, but the signatures for 
GetDB1 and GetDB2 are not equal, and Im obviously doing something ***not*** right.

```
val GetDB1 :
  name:string ->
    client:Choice<#MongoDB.Driver.IMongoClient,exn> ->
      Choice<MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase,exn>

val GetDB2 :
  name:string ->
    client:Choice<MongoDB.Driver.IMongoClient,exn> ->
      Choice<Choice<MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase,exn>,exn>
```

I have tried several versions and orders of doing things in GetDB2 but I more or less always end at same signature as above.

The general idea I initially had was to write small function doing the stuff they should and then add exception handling (**protect**) and then "wrap" and "unwrap" accordingly.

That might of course not be entirely right idea too.

Are someone able to point me in some directions here for further studies, code examples or anything? Any comments of any type are in fact welcome at this point ;-)

[FSharpx doc](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Extras/reference/fsharpx-choice.html)

**Addendum**

I think the following should be about same as above, but without the mongodb dependencies.

```
#r @".\packages\FSharpX.Extras\lib\net45\FSharpX.Extras.dll"

type DataBase = 
    {
        Name: string
    }

type Client = 
    {
        connectString: string
    } with member this.GetDatabase name = {
                        Name = name
                    }

open FSharpx.Choice
let private createClient (connectString:string) = {
  connectString= connectString
}

let CreateClient = protect createClient

let private getDb name (client:Client) = client.GetDatabase name

let GetDB1 name client =
    choose {
        let! c = client
        return! (protect (getDb name) c)
    }

let GetDB2 name client =
    protect (getDb name)
    <!> client
```

Comment: Could you, perhaps, express this as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I don't feel like fiddling with MongoDB in order to research this question...

Comment: BTW, in F# `<!>` is often used in place of Haskell's `<$>`, which isn't a legal operator in F#. It's simply an infix version of `map` (`fmap` in Haskell).

Comment: @MarkSeemann hehe. it is in fact MCVE. or that is: no need to fiddle with the mongos here ;-) the above run without any mongodb installed or any fiddling at all, if the pakets are in place. but I will try to do some more to the bone MCVE...

Comment: @MarkSeemann yes, i do have that understanding of <!>, the applicative is then more the <*> (I think). I did include the link to the doc of FSharpX for this reason...

Comment: In Haskell, `Applicative` is defined by `<*>` and `pure`. AFAICT, in FSharpx.Choice, these are `<*>` and `returnM`.

Comment: FWIW, our last comments crossed (I didn't see yours when I wrote mine). Not trying to preach to you, or anything...

Comment: I think you want something like `(=<<)` instead of `(<!>)`.

Comment: @kvb yes i want something like =<< or >>= but I do not manage to make it work as i want still...

Comment: @MarkSeemann hehe not my intention to make it seem like your preaching either. as I said initially, at this moment, Im very very happy anyone bothers to write any comments here. ;-)

Comment: @kvb and some more testing I managed it apperently. The MCVE of MarkSeeman did also possibly help me... client >>= protect (getDb name) seems to do the trick.... should I delete this question? Or does anyone want to actually answer it? Does it have any value this question? Anyhow thanks both!

Comment: You could answer it yourself :)

Comment: @MarkSeemann yes i could. with the "exact" code giving me the signature i wanted. the answer i really really want is probably more like a explanation of why (>>=) was right here, a general idea/code review, and evaluation of best practice and what not ;-) so somewhat to broad possibly... but it was not me answering it so do not want to "steal" it either... thanks again!

Comment: I see. I don't know if I can give a useful explanation, but `>>=` is 'just' the standard *bind* operator that, together with `return`/`pure`, defines a monad. In F# computation expressions, [`let!` bindings are translated to `Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions).

Comment: @MarkSeemann is it? same as bind? there is a difference in this fishy kleisli composition and an "ordinary" bind. i think. but the comments here are not for this type of discussions i guess ;-)

Comment: @MarkSeemann u are right and Im wrong. which kind of also set of all this initially. question and comments and all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the compounding of types here because you have used the `<!>` operator, which is `map`.  That is defined something like this:

```
let map f = function
    | Choice1Of2 value = Choice1Of2 (f value)
    | Choice2Of2 fail  = Choice2Of2 fail
```

This has the signature `('T -> 'U) -> Choice<'T,'Failure> -> Choice<'U,'Failure>`, i.e. the function `f` is used as a map *inside* the `choice` type.  For example:

```
map (sprintf "%d")
```

has type `Choice<int, 'Failure> -> Choice<string, 'Failure>`.  This is good for applying functions which do not use the `Choice` type - there is only one possible point of failure, and that happened before the call to `map`.

Your next function, however, produces a `Choice` type, but it takes a non-`Choice` type.  This means that you want the errors to propagate through - if there is an error in the value, then choose that.  If the value is fine, but there's an error in the function, then use that.  If everything is successful, use that.  This requires the two error types to be the same, which for you they are (`exn`).

This is describing the `bind` operation, defined like this:

```
let bind f = function
    | Choice1Of2 value = f value
    | Choice2Of2 fail  = Choice2Of2 fail
```

with signature `('T -> Choice<'U,'Failure>) -> Choice<'T,'Failure> -> Choice<'U,'Failure>`.

Note that `bind` is very similar to `map`, except that the latter raises the result into a `Choice1Of2` - the mapped function is always successful.

In FSharpX, you can access `bind` by the `|>`-like operator `>>=`, or the `<|`-like operator `<<=`.

Finally, `protect` is a fancy way of catching a thrown exception into a `Choice2Of2 exn`.  It is similar to `map` in that the passed function is of type `'T -> 'U`, but the function can also throw an exception and the passed type is *not* a `Choice`.   `protect` is defined something like this:

```
let protect f x =
    try
        Choice1Of2 (f x)
    with
        exn -> Choice2Of2 exn
```

so its signature is `('T -> 'U) -> 'T -> Choice<'U, exn>`.

For more information on how everything is implemented, see [the source of this computation expression](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Extras/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L739L858).

---

Putting this all together, we can see why your example went wrong.

- `getDb name` is a function `Client -> DataBase`
- `protect (getDb name)` is a function `Client -> Choice<DataBase, exn>`
- `map (protect (getDb name))` is therefore a function `Choice<Client, exn> -> Choice<Choice<DataBase, exn>, 'Failure>`, because `map` works inside `Choice`.

What you want, though, is

```
let GetDB name client =
    bind (protect (getDb name)) client
```

or in operator form,

```
let GetDB name client = client >>= protect (getDb name)
```

In general, if your mapping function has signature `'T -> 'U` you want `map`.  If it has `'T -> Choice<'U, 'Failure>`, you want `bind`.